# Find textbox in a group of shapes (VBA 6.3)

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am using VBA 6.3. In Excel I have a chart - left y axis on it and numbers. When I copy the Chart to powerpoint and degroup it, I leave the y axis only with the TextBoxes and the axis alone. Now I would like to obtain the minimum and maximum numbers beside the axis. First I tried to detect the TextBoxes it should be msoTextBox value 17. But when I checked the type number is 378*... I could not find out what is it (using google search). I need to obtain the two numbers and length of the axis line (so I can calculate the ratio  y_length/(max-min) ).

This is the code sofar.

```
Sub GetMinMax()
Dim YAxisMinMax() As Integer
With ActiveWindow.Selection
        If (.Type = ppSelectionShapes) And (.ShapeRange.Type = msoTextBox) Then
        Else
            MsgBox "Failed"
            Exit Sub
        End If
End With
End Sub
```

Rhe result - The Message is Failed. It did not found the TextGroup with number.

*Edit: I have found, that the type is different for every "text box". However the name of the shape is "rectangle", not a text box". It looks like text box, because it has text inside it.

Comment: How are you copying the chart from Excel and then de-grouping it?

Comment: You can read those values in Excel - using MaximumScale/MinimumScale of the axes-object. I suppose this is easier and more accurate

Comment: It is possible to do the Excel-stuff from Powerpoint - keeping the code in one place. Do you "know" the chart you want to copy? E.g. the sheetname etc?

Answer (score 0):

So far, this what I have done:

```
Option Explicit
Private Type T_HORIZONTAL_LINE
    ShortLineLeft As Integer
    ShortLineTop As Integer
    Length As Integer
    isFound As Boolean
End Type
Private Type T_VERTICAL_LINE
    ShortLineLeft As Integer
    ShortLineTop As Integer
    Length As Integer
    isFound As Boolean
End Type

Sub LookForAxis()
Dim Horizontal As T_HORIZONTAL_LINE
Dim Axis As T_VERTICAL_LINE

Dim YAxisMinMax(2) As Integer
Dim OldMinMax(2) As Integer
Dim Value As Integer
Dim Ratio As Single
Dim Text As String
Dim Sh As Shape

    With ActiveWindow.Selection
     If (.Type = ppSelectionShapes) And (.ShapeRange.Type = msoGroup) Then
      For Each Sh In .ShapeRange.GroupItems
        If Sh.Type = msoLine Then
            If (Axis.isFound) And (Horizontal.isFound) Then
            ElseIf (Sh.Width < Sh.Height) And (Not Axis.isFound) Then
              Axis.Length = Sh.Height
              Axis.ShortLineLeft = Sh.Left
              Axis.ShortLineTop = Sh.Top
              Axis.isFound = True
            ElseIf (Sh.Width > Sh.Height) And (Not Horizontal.isFound) Then
              Horizontal.Length = Sh.Width
              Horizontal.ShortLineLeft = Sh.Left
              Horizontal.ShortLineTop = Sh.Top
              Horizontal.isFound = True
           End If
        ElseIf (Sh.Type = msoAutoShape) And (Sh.HasTextFrame = msoTrue) Then
           Text = Sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
           Value = CInt(Text) ' Possibly: CLng()
           If Value < OldMinMax(1) Then
             OldMinMax(1) = Value
           ElseIf Value > OldMinMax(2) Then
             OldMinMax(2) = Value
           End If
        End If
      Next Sh
Ratio = Axis.Length / (OldMinMax(2) - OldMinMax(1)) ' Axis length div. axis range
        Else
            MsgBox "You have not selected an OBJECT in PowerPoint to dimension."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Notice: I have first placed all the axis lines and rectangles with TextFrame to one group to make it easy.